# Can't change process priority in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, task-manager, priority

I need to use MATLAB in realtime, but when I go to the Task Manager and try to change it, it's giving me an error:

> Unable to set Realtime priority. The priority was set to High instead.

I tried to do so with other applications, the result is the absolutely the same.

I am using Windows 7 Home Edition (Retail).

Comment: Do you have system admin privileges?

Comment: It's not asking me for any...

Comment: Are you just trying to eke out all of the performance you can on MATLAB, or does your application require real time processing?  If it's the latter, you may have to look into specific OS extensions that address this, as the scheduling on Windows is just a recommendation to the OS.

Comment: My application is for Realtime, but windows is not putting my app on 1st place, but if this happens out of testing it can be catastrophic...

Comment: Why do you think you need to run in the so-called real time priority range?